# make images only accessable from one domain

Tags: html, image, .htaccess

I have two domains. One (`imageserver.com`) is only for image upload. I want the pictures saved on the imageserver only accessible from the other domain (`showserver.com`) **and the image source should not be editable in the browser developer console/the requested URL should be denied because it did not come from the image server**.

I found a solution (htaccess for the imageserver):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?imageserver.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?showserver.com(/)?.*$ [NC]
```

But is this secure enough?

Does it prevent the visitor from changing the src of my img in his developer console and allowing an image that shouldn't be accessible to him to show up?

As an example:
The page outputs the image `<img src="https://imageserver.com/img/12">` and shows the image `12`. Then the user changes the src to`<img src="https://imageserver.com/img/13">`.

Would this output the image `13` or an error because the htaccess would deny this request?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Why not save images in non-web-accessible location and provide images using PHP? As PHP can access full server (depends on permissions) so it can output images

Comment: I am not uploading with my own script. I am using a "service" (WoltLab Gallery https://www.woltlab.com/apps/) where users of my site can upload images.
 I think i am not that good to develope a secure enough upload script.

Comment: Also consider hashing names of images. Instead of 12, 13...  use md5(time().12), md5(time().13)...

Comment: Of course i do that, but for showing i think numbers are easier

Comment: User will not read image url, so why to make him ease to guess next url?

Comment: No I mean here in stack overflow I use numbers to show you what I mean. In my service i will use hashed names